# Angular 2/4 managing form CRUD with parent/child components

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface

- I have a parent and a child component in which the parent is a list of repeating children using *ngFor.
- each child takes in an object through the @Input feature of angular and the child template is a form which is bound using angular 2 way binding letting you edit the objects properties.
- The parent is not necessarily a generic container/list for the child components and is not re-used for other lists.
- The parent uses an injected service to retrieve the list of data being used.

my question is, **who should call the update function when the form is being saved?** should the child have the service injected and it call the update function on the service? should it be passed to the parent to be updated? Should the child have read it to begin with?

I understand this could provoke opinionated answers so I am looking for an answer that would agree with what the Angular team intended for best practices and also match this criteria:

- even distribution between readability, performance and design.
- well rounded and related to commonly used software design patterns.

If any extra information is necessary please let me know, thanks!!

Comment: Though you already alluded to it, this is going to have incredibly opinionated answers. For myself, I have learned the hard way that trying to adhere to bandwagon best practices that are stemmed in little more than opinion will cause a world of headaches. Do what works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Pytth, I understand where you are coming from and certainly will receive answers with a grain of salt.

Comment: I had same doubt when I have used NG2BS3 modal where we have used operation buttons in modal footer as we are calling the data from services so we preferred to call all the operations from parent side. So I would say if you are using parent child relationship and depend on scenario you have to select the method you need to use. As in my case calling from parent was the best possible option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say, if parent component retrieves children using some service (most likely), then probably the same service handles save operation as well, and thus it is parent component who should be responsible for invoking save operation. In this case child should only generate event to inform the parent of user's intention to save this particular item. This way their responsibilities are better separated, since only one (parent) component is responsible for data operations on the service (one concern), while children are only responsible for showing and editing items (another concern).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it just depends on where your update-button is placed. If it's in the child component then call the service from child, otherwise call it from parent.